# Using NSoftware sftp adapter with Biztalk

Tags: biztalk, sftp, adapter

I've downlaoded the `nsoftware sftp adapter` for `Biztalk`.
I created a few send & receive ports within Biztalk admin just to see if it works, and it does.

I now need to build an orchestration with an sftp send port and sftp receive port.
I've added a reference to the adapter dll and included it in the project, but I'm not sure how to wire it up to my 2 ports in the `.odx` file.

Can anyone shove me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason you'd have a project-level reference to the adapter DLL is if you need to use the property schemas for the nsoftware adapter; otherwise, the way you'd use it is the same way you'd use any other BizTalk adapter:

- Declare your logical ports in your orchestration. Make sure you mark them as "Specify Later" (or direct/dynamic, if you're doing more advanced scenarios).
- Build your orchestration as usual
- Deploy
- Go to the BizTalk administration console and create receive locations/send ports as necessary specifying the nsoftware SFTP adapter. You'll be able to enter all the adapter configuration settings there.

If you could share any more details about what you're trying to do, maybe I could offer more specific advice.

Comment: thanks. basically as part of a bigger project I have biztalk sitting in the middle of several internal servers where files must be transfered with sftp.  Rather than just configuring the ports and letting them run through the admin console I need to do it with an orchestration as we wont always know the filename.  This wont be possible using just the ports as the send port expexts a full filename to be declared rather than say, *.xml, *.dat etc.
Ive been told I can do this with an orchestration though.

Comment: Assuming none of the usual macros will be enough for you, then yeah, you could do it through an orchestration (it's just one option, though).

Sounds like you're trying to use dynamic sends then, in which case, yeah, a combination of setting the right adapter URI right and using the context properties provided by the adapter would do the trick.